# How can I transpose columns at the end of my data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

I have a dataframe called data that looks like this

```
Record  Plot    Row Column  Cp  Csp Entry   Year    Location    Genotype    STD V1  V2  V3  W1  W2  W3
521 101 1   1   0   0   521 2019    Preston NxB-RIL-368-16      2   1   3   1   4   5   4
284 102 1   1   0   0   284 2019    Preston BxN-RIL-359-4       3   3   3   3   4   6   5
673 103 1   1   0   0   673 2019    Preston NxB-RIL-374-22      3   3   3   3   5   6   7
40  104 1   1   0   0   40  2019    Preston BxN-RIL-347-19      2   2   2   1   3   4   1
715 105 1   1   1   0   715 2019    Preston NorLin  3       2   3   2   3   5   0   0
108 106 1   1   0   0   108 2019    Preston BxN-RIL-351-2       2   2   3   2   5   6   5
456 107 1   1   0   0   456 2019    Preston NxB-RIL-365-18      2   2   4   3   0   3   2
```

What I would like to do is transform it to this

```
Record  Plot    Row Column  Cp  Csp Entry   Year    Location    Genotype Param Value    

521 101 1   1   0   0   521 2019    Preston NxB-RIL-368-16   STD    2
522 101 1   1   0   0   521 2019    Preston NxB-RIL-368-16   V1     2
523 101 1   1   0   0   521 2019    Preston NxB-RIL-368-16   V2 1
524 101 1   1   0   0   521 2019    Preston NxB-RIL-368-16   V3 3
525 101 1   1   0   0   521 2019    Preston NxB-RIL-368-16   W1 1
526 101 1   1   0   0   521 2019    Preston NxB-RIL-368-16   W2 4
527 101 1   1   0   0   521 2019    Preston NxB-RIL-368-16   W3 5
```

what I have tried is splitting up the data frame

```
col_idx <- grep("Genotype", names(data))
val_start <- col_idx + 1
val_end<-length(data) #last attribute column


d1 <- data[1:col_idx]
d2 <- data[val_start:val_end]
headerd2<-names( d2 )
```

and then iterateing over it to "re-assemble" it

```
for (colnum in 1:length(headerd2)) #colnum=2
{
 for (row in 1:nrow(d1)) 
  {
    d1$Param <- paste(gsub(" ","_",headerd2[colnum]), sep="")#create an environment attribute in the dataframe
    d1$Value <- paste(gsub(" ","_",d2[row, colnum]), sep="")#create an environment attribute in the dataframe
  write.table(d1, DataFilenameConverted, sep = ",", col.names = !file.exists(DataFilenameConverted), append = T)
 } 
}
```

as well I tried

```
library(reshape2)
d4 <-recast(data, Genotype + variable ~ Genotype, id.var = c("Record",   "Plot",     "Row",      "Column",   "Cp",       "Csp",      "Entry",    "Year" ,    "Location", "Genotype"))
```

both did not work , anhy advice on how to transform this data?

Comment: Can you provide your data using `dput` i.e `dput(data)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
tidyr::pivot_longer(dat, STD:W3, names_to = "Param", values_to = "Value")
# # A tibble: 49 x 12
#    Record  Plot   Row Column    Cp   Csp Entry  Year Location Genotype       Param Value
#     <int> <int> <int>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>    <chr>          <chr> <int>
#  1    521   101     1      1     0     0   521  2019 Preston  NxB-RIL-368-16 STD       2
#  2    521   101     1      1     0     0   521  2019 Preston  NxB-RIL-368-16 V1        1
#  3    521   101     1      1     0     0   521  2019 Preston  NxB-RIL-368-16 V2        3
#  4    521   101     1      1     0     0   521  2019 Preston  NxB-RIL-368-16 V3        1
#  5    521   101     1      1     0     0   521  2019 Preston  NxB-RIL-368-16 W1        4
#  6    521   101     1      1     0     0   521  2019 Preston  NxB-RIL-368-16 W2        5
#  7    521   101     1      1     0     0   521  2019 Preston  NxB-RIL-368-16 W3        4
#  8    284   102     1      1     0     0   284  2019 Preston  BxN-RIL-359-4  STD       3
#  9    284   102     1      1     0     0   284  2019 Preston  BxN-RIL-359-4  V1        3
# 10    284   102     1      1     0     0   284  2019 Preston  BxN-RIL-359-4  V2        3
# # ... with 39 more rows
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Record = c(521L, 284L, 673L, 40L, 715L, 108L, 456L), Plot = 101:107, Row = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Column = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Cp = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Csp = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Entry = c(521L, 284L, 673L, 40L, 715L, 108L, 456L), Year = c(2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L), Location = c("Preston", "Preston", "Preston", "Preston", "Preston", "Preston", "Preston"), Genotype = c("NxB-RIL-368-16", "BxN-RIL-359-4", "NxB-RIL-374-22", "BxN-RIL-347-19", "NorLin-3", "BxN-RIL-351-2", "NxB-RIL-365-18"), STD = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), V1 = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L), V2 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L), V3 = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L ), W1 = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 0L), W2 = c(5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 0L, 6L, 3L), W3 = c(4L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```